# Smooth NSWindow resize re: contentSize of WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview, nswindow, window-resize

Currently to resize a window whose contentView is a web view I do this:

```
let oldSize = webView.window?.contentView?.bounds.size
let webSize = <new asset size>
if oldSize != webSize, var origin = self.webView.window?.frame.origin {
    origin.y += ((oldSize?.height)! - webSize.height)
    webView.window?.setContentSize(webSize)
    webView.window?.setFrameOrigin(origin)
    webView.bounds.size = webSize
 }
```

which is fine but there's a sometimes lag between the contentSize change and the reposition to the visual origin. Attempts to use setFrame: are haphazard resulting is skewed content size.

Is there a way to buffer such window operations to affect a smooth transition. when WKWebView is involved?

Btw, in subsequent comment, this is the method used on the webView by its view:

```
func fit(_ childView: NSView, parentView: NSView) {
    childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    childView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    childView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use Autolayout. Just pin each side of the view to its superview, it will resize with the window, without extra lag.

Comment: I do call a fit() method at view load for the view adding the webView which adds constraints.

Answer (score 1):

This resize lag of `WKWebView` when resizing NSWindow, may be related to using the `fullSizeContentView` styleMask when initiating the window, or enabling the 'Full Size Content View' in the interface designer.

Comment: This did fix my problem, but broke my full height sidebar, which needs the `fullSizeContentView` style mask. I'll have to try something else.